# How to get a list of the activity history stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm struggling with an issue in my app. I'd like to provide a way to list the history of the previous opened activities.

I think there are two potential solutions but I'm not sure to find a stable way to achieve any of them.

- Somehow use a function from the SDK. I tried using getPackageManager() and getActivityManager() but I can't find any suitable solution
- Implement my own history but then I'll have to override startActivity and I don't really want to go down that way as an activity can be started in other multiple ways.

So is there a way to do that using a function from the SDK?

Many thanks.

EDIT:

I've got another idea, it's a bit different. Would it be possible to listen to "start/finish activity" events with some kind of receiver to a specific app (mine) and keep track of the stack history?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> So is there a way to do that using a function from the SDK?

No, sorry.

> Would it be possible to listen to "start/finish activity" events with some kind of receiver to a specific app (mine) and keep track of the stack history?

You can use `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()` on `Application`, if you are only going to support API Level 14 and higher (a.k.a., Android 4.0+).

Comment: If we use registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(), do we need to maintain our own stack? I actually want a list of ActivityRecords displayed for my application. I see that "adb shell dumpsys activity activities" displays a TaskRecord which has mulitple "Hist #" items which are ActivityRecords. I want a list of these ActivityRecords; atleast the activity class names. I don't find any method get this. This is with ref. to my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095772/get-thumbnail-screenshot-of-activities-in-back-stack-of-android?noredirect=1#comment48303570_30095772

Comment: @AndroidGuy: "do we need to maintain our own stack?" -- if you want a stack,yes.

Answer (score 43):

Using ADB commands:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity activities  # displays list of activities in back stack

adb shell dumpsys activity process  # displays list process in back stack

adb shell dumpsys activity intents  # displays list of pending intents in back stack

adb shell dumpsys activity broadcast  # displays list of broadcast in back stack

adb shell dumpsys activity services  # displays list of services running in back stack
```

Using Activity manager:

```
ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService( ctx.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfoList =  m.getRunningTasks(10);
Iterator<RunningTaskInfo> itr = runningTaskInfoList.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext()){
    RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = (RunningTaskInfo)itr.next();
    int id = runningTaskInfo.id;
    CharSequence desc= runningTaskInfo.description;
    int numOfActivities = runningTaskInfo.numActivities;
    String topActivity = runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getShortClassName();
}
```

Comment: But when activity is launched using intent-filter then the activity stack is empty.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the following method:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

int sizeStack =  am.getRunningTasks(2).size();

for(int i = 0;i < sizeStack;i++){

    ComponentName cn = am.getRunningTasks(2).get(i).topActivity;
    Log.d("", cn.getClassName());
}
```

get a list of the activity stack.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this method, it's specified in the documentation it should only be used for a debug purpose. thanks anyway :)

Comment: That only provides the list of tasks, not the list of activities in a stack (one task). Each tasks contains numActivities and those are not listed anywhere.

Comment: Just a comment. If you want to use that method you have to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" /> to the list of permissions in the Android Manifest.

Comment: What does 2 mean here? Any reference?

Comment: @YuchenZhong Check the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getRunningTasks(int) "the maximum number of entries to return in the list. The actual number returned may be smaller, depending on how many tasks the user has started."

Answer (score -2):

A very simple way to achieve Activity History is with classes name

define `activity_history_list` in your `mainActivity`

```
public static List<String> activity_history_list;
```

and in every `onStart()` of every activity you create
(for example `MainActivity`)

```
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        activity_history_list.add(MainActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
```

in a another activity (for example `SettingActivity`)

```
 @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            MainActivity.activity_history_list.add(SettingActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
```

You can access `activity_history_list` anywhere as long as it's `static`, 
you can print all history at once or access a specific activity in history by `index`

Comment: This depends on each and every Activity call a specific function, but you might forget to add it to one or you may be opening an Activity you don't own. Using @CommonsWare's answer is better since the app listens to any Activity the app opens regardless if you've remembered to put the activity history list code in onStart https://stackoverflow.com/a/13674742/818821